# Get coefficients of all discrete states from glm in R

Tags: r, dataframe, glm

I have a dataframe which has a discrete column with the following states

```
StateName          PX127857  PX128030  PX100049  PX100330  PX106316  PX115690  PX125484  PX112410 PX100778     
    Support           1          1         8         4         7         5         8         12        13
```

when i fit the dataframe with glm using

```
  model<- glm(formula, data = DATAFRAME, family = "binomial")
```

model$coefficients returns the coefficients of only 8 out of the 9 discrete states , 
For the state PX128030   , i do not get any coefficient

I think i understand why this might be happening but is there a way to return null or 0 for  states like PX128030 so that the order and count of **model$coefficients**  is the same as **levels(dataframe $column)**
?

Comment: you can usually use `-1` or `+0` in the formula to suppress the intercept, which should give you coefficients for every state (might not work properly if your model is complex, you haven't shown us)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a basic stats problem. When you put a categorical variable into a model, you are unable to calculate an effect for each level. You need a constraint to make the problem solvable. You can deal with that in a number of ways, but the most common in R is to assign one level as a reference level and then the coefficients for all the other levels are actually measures of how different that level is from the reference level. So the effect for that reference level is not 0, it's simple tied up in the estimate of the intercept. The reference level is usually the first level of the factor.

I think all the terms are stored in the `xterms` property of the model. Maybe a helper function like this might be of use

```
levelvals<-function(m) {
    ml <- m$xlevels
    fv<-lapply(names(ml), function(x) v<-paste(x, ml[[x]],sep=""))
    cf <- coefficients(m)
    r<-lapply(fv, function(v) {structure(cf[v], names=v)})
    names(r)<-names(ml)
    r
}
m<-lm(y~f, dd)
levelvals(m)
```

But just make sure you are correctly interpreting the parameters. Those are not the means for each level, those are the differences in means between that level and the reference level.

Comment: the code will not work because the names of model$coefficients are not the same as levels(df$column) because glm appends the columnname along with the staet for ex if in the dataframe the column name is "col" and the state is PX127857   , then model$coefficients will produce the coefficient for "colPX127857" and not "PX127857" . I can trim the colname from the coefficient name but is there a better way?

Comment: and yes , the reference level in my case is a  missing valeue with level "" .

Comment: @user2912902 I've updated the code with something I think should work.

Comment: It does not add the state name of the missing state from the coefficients (just adds the column name and value 'NA'). I can work with that but the problem is that it does not preserve the order . The missing state 'PX128030'  is added to the beginning with value 'NA'

Comment: @user2912902 Because you did't supply a fully reproducible example, I can't test it out on your data. If you like, you can edit the question to include all the details/data needed to reproduce your problem.